# make multiplie input text required on checkbox

Tags: javascript, html

I have a table with many rows and each row has a checkbox and an input.

I'm tring to make a code snippet that will make the input reqiured when the checkbox on the same row is checked.

Here is what I have tried:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#prod[1]').click(function() {
        if ($(this).prop('checked')) {
            $('#qty_1').attr('required', '');
        } else {
            $('#qty_1').removeAttr('required');
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox" id="prod[1]"><label for="prod[1]">name</label></td>
        <td><input type="text" id="qty_1" name="qty_1"></td>
</tr>
```

This one isn't working because of the "[]", however, if I remove them, they will work...

I dont know how to make it work with the "[]" or for each row (prod[2], prod[3], etc...)

Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Those brackets have special meaning in css(attribute selector), to use these characters in your jquery selector need to escape them by using double backslashes `\\`.
Check out the snippet, write down anything inside the textbox before clicking on the check-box and watch the console log result.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
var prod = $('#prod\\[1\\]');
  prod.on('click', function() {
    if ($(this).prop('checked')) {
      $('#qty_1').attr('required', '');
    } else {
      $('#qty_1').removeAttr('required');
    }
    console.log($('#qty_1').val());
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<tr>
  <td><input type="checkbox" id="prod[1]"><label for="prod[1]">name</label></td>
  <td><input type="text" id="qty_1" name="qty_1"></td>
</tr>
```

Comment: From there any form of iteration should be able to replace the [] with a number and the id with a class. You have a spelling error - attribute.

Comment: ok thank you! i didnt know that! can you help me with making it work for every "prod[ID]" that i have? it's taking the data from sql databse... how i can make it work?

Comment: use `var prod = $('#prod\\[' + $YOUR_PHP_ID_STATEMENT + '\\]');` instead of `var prod = $('#prod\\[1\\]');`

Comment: i did that, for each one - i put this code in the loop.... there is no other way to make this? i think it's preety bad idea.... (?)

Comment: you need to give an example of what exactly you need help with so , just add some code with what exactly you need